# Capture SendPlayStateChangeEvents from Embedded Player

Tags: javascript, vb.net, media-player

I am using the following script to embed a media player:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('<OBJECT id="Player"');
        document.write(' classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"');
        document.write(' width=210 height=60>');
        document.write(' <PARAM name="Volume" value="100">');
        document.write(' <PARAM NAME="SendPlayStateChangeEvents" VALUE="True">');
        document.write(' <PARAM name="uiMode" value="full"></OBJECT>');
</script>
```

I am trying to capture the "SendPlayStateChangeEvents" for example, when I stop the player:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getPlayState(){
        var getit = document.getElementById("Player");
        getit.settings.volume = 100;
        alert(getit.PlayState); 
    }
</script>
```

The "getPlayState() function does not work...

How can I monitor the PlayState using JavaScript?

(I am using vs web dev 2010, windows 7, vb.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out...

The embedding is correct:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('<OBJECT id="Player"');
        document.write(' classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"');
        document.write(' width=210 height=60>');
        document.write(' <PARAM name="Volume" value="100">');
        document.write(' <PARAM NAME="SendPlayStateChangeEvents" VALUE="1">');
        document.write(' <PARAM name="uiMode" value="full"></OBJECT>');
    </script>
```

In order to monitor the SendPlayStateChangeEvents, you need to set up a timer in the script by using the setInterval(function().

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function showPlayer() {
           $('a.play').on("click", function (event) {
               var t = event.clientY;
               var l = event.clientX + 200;
               $(Player).css("position", "fixed").css("top", t + "px").css("left", l + "px");
               $(Player).show();
               myVar = setInterval(function () { getPlayerStatus() }, 2000);
           })
       }
    </script>
```

Then the timer will check for event changes every two seconds. In this case, it checks for "stop' or "ready", then halts the timer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getPlayerStatus() {
        var s = Player.PlayState;
        if (s == 1 || s == 10) {
            $(Player).hide();
            setTimeout(myStopFunction(), 500);
        };
    }
    function myStopFunction() {
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
</script>
```

Hope this information is helpful to someone....